# How can I hide or organize workflows in Github Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a Github repository with several workflows. My repository structure looks like

```
-- .github/
---- workflows/
------ workflow_1
------ workflow_2
...
------ workflow_10
```

Some of these workflows run in response to a pull request merging, while others are manually triggered. But, when I go to the `Actions` tab of my github repository, I see all of the workflows in my repository listed in one list. This makes it difficult to use the github actions tab for manually triggered workflows since engineers at my company need to look through a long list of workflows to find the ones that bring up an interface for running their action.

I would like to be able to hide or separate the workflows that are triggered on merge from those that are triggered manually so that the manually triggered workflows are easy to find.

Something like:

```
Actions
-- All Workflows/
---- Manually Triggered/
------- manual_workflow
----- Merge Triggered/
------- on_merge_workflow
```

Or to be able to hide the merge triggered workflows entirely.

I read GitHub's [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/about-workflows#understanding-the-workflow-file) on managing workflows, but didn't find any information about hiding or organizing workflows. It does not seem like the `on` parameter can be used to do this from what I can tell.

**Update:**

Per Azeem's comment, it does not seem like this is possible atm. Instead, I added emojis to the beginnings of the names of the workflow files to make it easier to sort through them visually.

Comment: Looks like currently there's no feature available to segregate workflows like that. A search box would definitely help but it's not there too. One thing that you can do is to add this info in the workflow name e.g. "**CodeQL (manual)**". That should help. Apart from that, you may [start a GHA discussion](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/new?category=actions) for this feature.

Comment: I just created a new discussion thread: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/53383

Comment: Thank you. I ended up adding emojis to the names of my workflow names to categorize them

Comment: Organizing by emojis is awesome!  Here's a list of Github emojis: https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/7360908

Answer (score 0):

That is currently not possible and I am not aware of any plans from Github Actions team to implement this feature.

All you can do is to rely on the fact that they are alphabetically sorted.